# input() typing issue

Tags: python, if-statement

```py
x = True
y = False
i = input("How many nose you have : ")

ans = 1

if i == 1:
    print(x)
elif i == 2:
    print(y)
print(ans)
```

If I give an input of 2, it should print the value of `y`. However, it is not printing the value of `y` for this input. I'm not sure how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

`input()` returns a string. You should use:

```py
i = int(input("How many nose you have : "))
```

to cast the input to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

the thing is input() from python takes everything in string, to use it in other datatype you have to typecast it or compare in string

```
x = True
y = False
i = input("How many nose you have : ")

ans = 1

if int(i)==1:
    print(x)
elif int(i)==2:
    print(y)
print(ans)
```

Comment: `x = True
y = False
i = int(input("How many nose you have : "))`


`ans = str(1)`

`if i == 1:
    print(x)
else:
    print(False)
print("The answer is " + ans)`

Comment: I done like this

Answer (score 0):

```
x = True
y = True
i = int(input("How many nose you have: "))

ans = 1

if i == 1:
    print(x)
elif i == 2:
    print(y)
print(ans)
```

Though I don't recommend doing it like this because you can still do 3 and other numbers. I'd recommend doing it like this instead:

```
a = int(input("How many nose do you have?: "))
ans = 1

if a == ans:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
print("The answer is " + ans + "!")
```